# AVPlayer layer not showing video content

Tags: ios, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I am using multiple AVPlayers to display content on my screen and they are all playing video simultaneously. 
The issue is that sometimes the avplayer is playing but the avplayerlayer isn't showing anything- all you get is a blank screen. This happens randomly. I don't even know how to debug this.

Has anyone had these same issues with AVPLayers or AVPlayer layers? Can you reference the same alaasset from different players at the same time? I'm guessing that these

Comment: what kind of content are you trying to play?

Comment: Did you solve this? Sometimes it's related to the frame size of the player layer not being set.

Comment: @user2924482  It was video content.

Comment: @Crashalot I think there is a limit to how many videos you can play simultaneously. We sort of maxed out at 4. So after that iOS begins to misbehave.

Comment: Still having this issue with only 1 AVPlayer on iPadOS 14. Sound can be heard but not image. When dismissing the app to the background and going back, image is working. How to solve it? On iOS it works fine everytime.

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue when the URL video I was trying to play did not have an extension. After I appended mp4 as path extension, the video started to play in the layer.